# Comparing a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I want to compare a list of tuples, if the first elements are the same then compare the second elements and return the highest.

```
lis = [(1,10, "n"), (1,15,"n1"), (2,20,"n"),(2,35,"n1"),(3,123,"n"),(3,12,"n1")]
```

return:

```
lis = [(1,15,"n1"), (2,35,"n1"), (3,123,"n")]
```

I'm not sure how to go about this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `itertools.groupby` to first group all items with the same first element together, then `max` to find the items with the max second element.

Unlike some other answers you may have varying number of elements from different "groups".

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lis = [(1,10, "n"), (1,15,"n1"), (2,20,"n"), (2,35,"n1"), (3,123,"n"),(3,12,"n1")]

lis.sort(key=itemgetter(0))  # groupby requires the iterable to be sorted,
                             # so making sure it is

grouped_by = groupby(lis, key=itemgetter(0))

output = [max(li, key=itemgetter(1)) for group, li in grouped_by]
print(output)

# [(1, 15, 'n1'), (2, 35, 'n1'), (3, 123, 'n')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Tuple comparisons do that already, comparing first elements then second and continuing until a tie-breaker is found.

All you need to do is `zip` the list in such a way to create the correct comparisons:

```
zip(lis[::2], lis[1::2])
# This produces:
# (1, 10, 'n') (1, 15, 'n1')
# (2, 20, 'n') (2, 35, 'n1')
# (3, 123, 'n') (3, 12, 'n1')
```

Creates the pairs you need, you can then compare them inside a list-comprehension to get the wanted results:

```
r = [i if i > j else j for i,j in zip(lis[::2], lis[1::2])]
print(r)
# [(1, 15, 'n1'), (2, 35, 'n1'), (3, 123, 'n')]
```

Comment: This will only work if the list contains 2 elements of each "type".

Comment: Judging from the sample and lack of an explicit remark stating otherwise, I was pretty sure that's the only case @DeepSpace. If required, `zip_longest` with a `fillvalue` of `()` can be used.

Comment: `result = [[j,i][i>j] for i,j in zip(lis[::2],lis[1::2])]` is somehow more "pythonic" isn't it?

Comment: @Claudio I wouldn't say so. That clearly is less readable than the solutions here. Search around and you'll see a number of questions from other people regarding the indexing trick you're employing and how it trips them up :-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution using [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) and [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) functions:

```
lis = [(1,10, "n"), (1,15,"n1"), (2,20,"n"),(2,35,"n1"),(3,123,"n"),(3,12,"n1")]
result = [max(lis[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(lis), 2)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[(1, 15, 'n1'), (2, 35, 'n1'), (3, 123, 'n')]
```

Comment: This will only work if the list contains 2 elements of each "type".

Comment: @DeepSpace what do you mean by this ?

Comment: @qwertyayyy you'd get wrong output if for example `lis = [(1,10, "n"), (1,15,"n1"), (1,20,"n1"), (2,20,"n"),(2,35,"n1"),(3,123,"n"),(3,12,"n1")]`

Comment: @DeepSpace thank you for that. That is exactly what I want the code to do.